# Programatically import all files in a folder to a list

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I'm somewhat new to Python, so there probably are many mistakes in my approach. I've been searching for this for a while but was unable to find or implement a solution. Maybe it's due to how I'm thinking about this problem so I'm open to different takes

I'm working on a batch tool. It should be able to use different file types.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
/__init__.py
/...other files...
/Exporter/
/Exporter/ExporterA.py
/Exporter/ExporterB.py
...
/Exporter/ExporterN.py
```

Those exporter files implement the same interfaces to operate on the Different file types A,B...N. And I want to import those in a way to allow me to access whatever interfaces are implemented on that folder through a list, as such:

```py
for exporter in exporters:
    exporter.foo_export_interface()
```

Or something similar.

I've tried a few different combinations with os.path and other tools to track the files in /Exporter/ and importing them with importlib, but it always fail with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named`.

A partially working solution I had involved creating a `/Exporter/__init__.py` and programmatically adding the filenames to **all**, and then in the file that would use the exporters adding a `from Exporters import *`. It "worked" but I was missing a clean way of getting hold of those objects that were imported.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It answered my question to some extent. I managed to figure it out thanks to the answers provided there, but there were some gaps I had to fill myself. Should I edit my answer to fill in the details?